# C# MVC Active Directory No search result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, active-directory

I have a problem in my SearchResult querying Active Directory. Here is what I try to do: I can search users from Active Directory and then show their name in a link form. This works. Then when you click on link it has to show all the information on the user. I uses lists to pass the query results, and when I search a name in Active Directory I have a full list of results, but when try to show the information of a specific user, my list is always null and I can't figure out why.

Here is my search result page with the links:

```
@{
    var incLoop = 0;
    var incArr = 0;
    var list = (List<string>)ViewData["Names"];
    var size = list.Count();
    string[] objSID = new string[size];
    foreach (var link in list)
    {
        if (incLoop % 2 == 0)
        {
            objSID[incArr] = link;
            incArr++;
            <p>@incArr</p>
        }
        else
        {

           <a href="@Url.Action("ShowUserInfo", "Home", new {sAMAccountName=objSID[incArr-1]})">@link</a>


        }
        incLoop++;
    }
}
```

When you click the link, it then does a research of AD using sAMAccountName parameter, here is the controller :

```
public ActionResult ShowUserInfo(string name)
{
    ADManager adManager = new ADManager();
    List<string> info = adManager.UserInformation(name);
    if (info != null)
    {
        ViewData["UserInfo"] = info;
        return View();
    }
    else
        return View("SearchUser");
}
```

And finally here is my function that searches in AD from the ADManager class

```
public List<string> UserInformation(string SAMAccountName)
    {
        try
        {
            DirectoryEntry ldapConnection = createDirectoryEntry();
            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(ldapConnection);

            search.Filter = "(sAMAccountName="+ SAMAccountName + ")";
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("userPrincipalName");
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("description");
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("accountExpires");
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("profilePath");
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("objectSID");
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("anr");
            resultCollection = search.FindAll();
            //result = search.FindOne();
            foreach (SearchResult sr in resultCollection)
            {
                lastName.Add(sr.Properties["anr"][0].ToString());
                lastName.Add(sr.Properties["displayName"][0].ToString());
                lastName.Add(sr.Properties["userPrincipalName"][0].ToString());
                lastName.Add(sr.Properties["description"][0].ToString());
                lastName.Add(sr.Properties["accountExpires"][0].ToString());
                lastName.Add(sr.Properties["memberOf"][0].ToString());
                lastName.Add(sr.Properties["profilePath"][0].ToString());
                lastName.Add(sr.Properties["objectSID"][0].ToString());
            }

            return lastName;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception caught:\n\n" + e.ToString());
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

createDirectoryEntry() allows to create the connection to AD, and ADManager class contains all the access functions to AD. Normally I should be able to use a simple SearchResult.FindOne() for this query since sAMAccountName is unique but it didn't work so I tried with collections (since this works for searching all users using anr parameter from AD).

EDIT: I forgot to say that I have an exception: System.ArgumentException in System.DirectoryServices.dll when I click on user links. So probably the problem comes from ADManager search query.
Thanks for your help, if unclear I can add precision.

Comment: Your name parameter you are passing to ShowUserInfo looks wrong.

Comment: Try passing it like so `new {sAMAccountName = "(objectSid=<YourSID>)"`

Comment: Not working. objSID represents sAMAccountName, sry I forgot to change since I was searching with objectSID at first (but conversion problems so I switch to easier).

Comment: Note that, when I use the above, my URL looks like this: http://localhost:64372/Home/ShowUserInfo?sAMAccountName=leonard

Comment: So sAMAccountName is correctly retrieved and passed as argument, then I can use search.Filter("sAMAccountName=leonard") but it doesn't work

Comment: are you shure its not the CommonName `cn` instead of `sAMAccountName`? Also try using `*` like so: `sAMAccountName=*leonard*`.

Comment: Tried the suggestion it doesn't work either.Maybe cn can work, but replacing here doesn't work. I think there is a problem when I pass the sAMAccount argument, probably the controller doesn't recognize it, idk. I'm pretty sure that the problem is in ADManager, since my controller function works and returns View("SearchUser") everytime. So I guess in ADManager I get no result from my request.

Comment: I found one mistake that has to do with the propertiesToLoad() function, I think one of the properties is invalid. If I replace my searchFilter: search.Filter("sAMAccountName=leonard") it works! So I guess the argument is the only thing wrong now, because if I put back to argument call in the filter, it's not working anymore.

Comment: Wow, the solution was so stupid: I call in <a href...> sAMAccountName but I had to use the name of variable in my function definition, i.e 'name' in ShowUserInfo... Thanks for the help :)